# React fetch error when trying to send Id with input data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, get, fetch-api

I have a little problem with react fetch while trying to send data to my database.

I have a list of teams and I would like to add players to certain teams. I am trying to send player name and player number from user input and team ID from the specific team they are adding the player to. This is my function for adding players:

```
  addPlayers() {
    var pname = document.getElementById("playerName").value;
    var pnr = document.getElementById('pnr').value;
    var teamId = document.getElementById('teamId').value;
    console.log(pname + pnr + teamId);
    fetch("http://localhost:8080/api/addPlayer?name="+pname+"&number="+pnr+"&teamId="+teamId);
 }
```

It all works if I hard code player name and number or when I hard code teamID. When trying to get all 3 dynamically it does not work. The console.log simply returns the team ID and that also does not update when trying to add players to other teams.

React render part:

```
  this.state.data.map((dynamicData, key) =>
              <div class="black">
              <PanelGroup accordion id="accordion">
                <Panel bsStyle="primary" eventKey="1">
                  <Panel.Heading>
                    <Panel.Title toggle>{dynamicData.name} <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></Panel.Title>
                  </Panel.Heading>
                  <Panel.Body collapsible>Add players</Panel.Body>
                  <Panel.Body collapsible>
                  <div id="dynamicInput">
                    <input type="hidden" class="bottomroom" id="teamId" value={dynamicData.id}></input>
                    <input type="text" class="bottomroom" placeholder="Player name" id="playerName"></input>
                    <input type="text" class="bottomroom" placeholder="Player number" id="pnr"></input>
                  </div>
                    <br></br>
                    <button type="submit" onClick={this.addPlayers} class="btn btn-success button"><i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i></button>
                  </Panel.Body>
                </Panel>
              </PanelGroup>
```

[Here is a picture of what it looks like to give you a better understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2TeQ.png)

[image]

---

Error:

```
"Bad Request"
message
:
"Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: """
path
:
"/api/addPlayer"
status
:
400
timestamp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at the error it's obvious that there is type mismatch for the field.

I will assume number field is of int type can you try following or if it's teamid which is of type int just do this for teamid

```
var pnr = parseInt(document.getElementById('pnr').value);
```

Tell us if it works.

**UPDATE**

```
<input type="text" class="bottomroom" placeholder="Player name" id={"playerName"+key}></input>
<input type="text" class="bottomroom" placeholder="Player number" id={"pnr"+key}></input>
```

for button

```
 <button type="submit" onClick={() => this.addPlayers(key)} class="btn btn-success button"><i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i></button>
```

and in function

```
   addPlayers(key) {
    var pname = document.getElementById("playerName").value;
     var pnr = parseInt(document.getElementById('pnr').value);
    var teamId = document.getElementById('teamId').value;
    console.log(pname + pnr + teamId);
    fetch("http://localhost:8080/api/addPlayer?name="+pname+"&number="+pnr+"&teamId="+teamId);
 }
```

Comment: The error remains the same but console now logs NaN and teamID as opposed to just the teamID that it logged before.

Comment: Well, did you console logged all variables? are the values coming properly of prn,teamid?

Comment: Yes, that's what seems to be the problem. For some reason only teamID is logging, player name is just an empty log and player number is NaN. I am not sure how these can affect eachother as if I just deleted teamID from the input fields then the player name and number inputs would log properly.

Comment: I think it's because of value attribute, just try to add value attribute manually to pnr and name and set some value and try (Don't type anything just click button)

Comment: If I set the playername to, for example 'eddie' and number to 10 then yes, it works.  For some reason the user entered data gets lost somewhere.

Comment: Ok, tell me is this same for all teams? like Kanad etc? If yes then all the inputs have the same id and that is causing the main problem.

Comment: And if thats the case just append the key to id (If key is unique) and pass it to addPlayer and append again where you are taking values by elementId.